# How does Find Traps work?

Tags: baldurs-gate, baldurs-gate-enhanced

I'm playing Baldur's Gate Enhanced Edition and I have a thief (Safana) with 100 in Find Traps.  I'm in the third level of the Nashkel Mines dungeon and there are traps that she doesn't seem to be able to detect*.  I've been standing right in front of a trap for over a minute now with the trap remaining undetected.  There are a few details that I'm confused about that don't seem to be documented anywhere.

- What is the maximum time I may have to wait to detect a trap?
- Are there traps that require >100 in Find Traps to be detected?  (or are these traps undetectable at any value of Find Traps?)
- When the roll is made to determine if your thief finds a trap, is that roll permanent?  IE is it possible that the thief will later succeed in detecting a trap that initially went undetected?  If so, what conditions need to be met to make this possible?

*: Realized later that I hadn't consistently been enabling Find Traps.  I think this is the reason that I failed to find traps.  Yep, that would do it.

Answer (score 3):

I opened the manual with [a better OSX PDF viewer than Preview](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) and managed to find the Thieving Abilities section where this skill is documented in some detail.  From the book:

> Thieves can select Find Traps, and they will look around for traps
>   until otherwise directed. At the start of each round while the
>   Detection mode is active, the Thief’s Find Traps skill (modified by a
>   simple d10 roll) is compared against any traps within sight of the
>   Thief. If the Thief’s modified skill is higher than the difficulty
>   rating of the trap, the trap is detected. Note that this skill does
>   not benefit from having more than 100 points assigned to it.

So it should only be necessary, most of the time, to wait 6 seconds for the start of the next round to detect any traps within sight.  I ran through the level again and this seemed to hold true.  Earlier, I might not have consistently remembered to reactivate Find Traps after reactivating Stealth.  I'm still curious about how the Find Traps skill is modified, but it sounds like the d10 is added to it, since otherwise it would be useful to have up to 110 points assigned to Find Traps.  Assuming that traps can have a difficulty rating up to 100.

Answer (score 0):

the highest trap difficulty in the game is 110 (and there's only 3 that high. The rest are around 80-95 at the upper end, especially in BG2 where thief NPCs were rarer and you were expected to potentially be having to make due with a low level DC'd thief).

BG uses a threshold system, where a d10 is rolled and your relevant skill is added to it, and if it meets the requirement you detect/disable/unlock it.

There's one in BG2 with a 1000 difficulty, but that's cause you're not supposed to be able to disable/detect that one, due to the nature of the trap.

As above it also only pulses once per round, so you may run into traps due to them being outside the pulse radius, especially once you get access to boots of speed/haste spells and are covering a lot of ground quickly.